# Cascade replication in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, replication

I have 2 MariaDB databases with master-master replication enabled(let's call them `master1` and `master2`). I wanted to set up additional 2 nodes (`extra1` and `extra2`), one replicating from another and first replicating from `master2`. Overall setup would look like that:

```
+-------+ +----------> +-------+
|master1|              |master2|
+-------+ <----------+ +---+---+
                           |
                           |
                           |
                        +--v---+
                        |extra1|
                        +--+---+
                           |
                           |
                           |
                        +--v---+
                        |extra2|
                        +------+
```

However, when i set up replication(first between `extra1` and `extra2`, `extra1` as master and `extra2` as slave) everything worked fine, so i thought adding `master2` as master for `extra1` will work without problem as well.

Apparentely, this configuration doesn't work, and replication works only within a single connection.

Example: i create a table on `master1`, it appears on `master2` as expected. However, it does not go further (doesn't appear on neither `extra1` and `extra2`). Following this pattern, i tried creating table on `master2` to check if it will behave similarly, and it did (new table appeared on both `master1` and `extra1`, but not `extra2`).

How should i approach this issue? Is there a hidden option that enables such cascade replication? This configuration doesn't seem very specific, but i couldn't really much of information on it.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some digging, i was able to find proper answer for that. Nodes that are in-between need to have `log_slave_updates = 1` option in `my.cnf` file.

Maybe someone will have easier time in the future when they search for this!